# If them else in clips error

Tags: function, clips

I need test one input with the base. It's agree. But when the user input two words who exist in base the function don't inform erro. Therefore I need to use "if then else" for test this case.

error: [ARGACCES4] Function DeleteOneSynSoftgoal expected exactly 1 argument(s), but if I define more arguments it's appear erro too.

Someone can help me. Thanks

```
(deffunction Deleting::DeleteOneSynSoftgoal (?f )"This rule delete one synsoftagoal found in the basis of fact." 
   (printout t "Enter below the two softgoals field that want to be deleting:" crlf crlf
             "the synonyms of the <[TYPE]QUALITY ATTRIBUTE> and the <[TOPIC]SUBJECT/OBJECT LAL> need to be entered one per line." crlf crlf)
   (bind ?dsyntype (readline))
   (bind ?dsyntopic (readline))
   (if  (do-for-all-facts((?f synSoftgoal)) (and(eq ?f:syntype ?dsyntype)(eq ?f:syntopic ?dsyntopic)))
     then
      (retract ?f)
       else
     (printout t "meta nao encontrada")
   (printout t crlf "The SynSoftgoals were successfully deleted" crlf)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no facts satisfying the do-for-all-facts query, then the value FALSE will be returned. Otherwise the last action for the last fact satisfying the query will be the return value, so if you add the value TRUE after the (retract ?f) action, the return value of do-for-all-facts will be TRUE if at least one fact is retracted.

It's not clear what your purpose was for making ?f a parameter of the deffunction since it isn't used anywhere inside function other than within the do-for-all-facts query which will shadow the deffunction parameter with its own definition of ?f.

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate synSoftgoal (slot syntype) (slot syntopic) (slot x))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts info
   (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 1))
   (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 2))
   (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 3))
   (synSoftgoal (syntype "d") (syntopic "e") (x 4))
   (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 5))
   (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 6)))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction DeleteOneSynSoftgoal () 
   (printout t "dsyntype? ")
   (bind ?dsyntype (readline))
   (printout t "dsyntopic? ")
   (bind ?dsyntopic (readline))
   (if (do-for-all-facts ((?f synSoftgoal)) 
                          (and (eq ?f:syntype ?dsyntype) (eq ?f:syntopic ?dsyntopic))
          (retract ?f)
          TRUE)
     then
     (printout t "The SynSoftgoals were successfully deleted" crlf)
     else
     (printout t "No SynSoftgoals deleted" crlf)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 1))
f-2     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 2))
f-3     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 3))
f-4     (synSoftgoal (syntype "d") (syntopic "e") (x 4))
f-5     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 5))
f-6     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 6))
For a total of 7 facts.
CLIPS> (DeleteOneSynSoftgoal)
dsyntype? x
dsyntopic? y
No SynSoftgoals deleted
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 1))
f-2     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 2))
f-3     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 3))
f-4     (synSoftgoal (syntype "d") (syntopic "e") (x 4))
f-5     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "b") (x 5))
f-6     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 6))
For a total of 7 facts.
CLIPS> (DeleteOneSynSoftgoal)
dsyntype? a
dsyntopic? b
The SynSoftgoals were successfully deleted
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-2     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 2))
f-4     (synSoftgoal (syntype "d") (syntopic "e") (x 4))
f-6     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 6))
For a total of 4 facts.
CLIPS> (DeleteOneSynSoftgoal)
dsyntype? d
dsyntopic? e
The SynSoftgoals were successfully deleted
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-2     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 2))
f-6     (synSoftgoal (syntype "a") (syntopic "c") (x 6))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help again.